# jhipster gateway microservice : npm start failled with " Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...s.org\r\n\r\nwsFcBAEB' "

Tags: spring-boot, npm, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

i m trying to test a basic microservice architecture with jHipster .

the gateway microservice on jhipster shot me this error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just fixed my problem with a simple clean cache and npm install

```
> npm cache clean --force
> npm install
```